# for文でリスト名が入ったリストを回し、そのインデックスを取得したい

Tags: python

例えば

```
names = [a,b,c,d]
```

というリスト名が入ったリストがあるとして

```
a = [1,2,3] 
b = [4,5,6] ...
```

というインデックスが別に用意されている時に
for文でa,b,c,dの文字を取得し、その名に対応するリストにインデックスの1要素ずつを取得したいと思っていますが、以下のように回すと#のようにリスト名自体が表示されてしまいます。
1,2,3...とインデックスを出すにはどのように改善すれば良いのでしょうか

```
for index, name in enumrate(names):
　　for i in enumrate(name):
　　　　print(name[i])
#a
#b
#c
#d
```

Comment: `names = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], ...]` という形になっている、という認識で良いでしょうか？

Comment: [`globals()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1373201/2072269)使ってできますが、別の方法使ったほうがいいと思います。

Comment: いいえ、それぞれ別のものになっています。

Comment: `names = [a,b,c,d]`ですか、`names = ["a","b","c","d"]` ですか？

Comment: `names = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]` ということでしょうか？

Comment: 一例としては、`for i in enumrate(name):` の部分を `for v in vars()[name]:` に変更して、`print(name[i])` を `print(v)` に変更すれば良いかな、とは思います。

Answer (score 1):

[enumerate](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) はインデックスと値を列挙する組み込み関数です。
単純に要素を出したい場合はinの後にnameを記述すれば取得できます。
単純にインデックスを出したい場合はrange関数を使えば0から始まるインデックスが取得できます。

質問文の`enumrate`を`enumerate`に書き換えても変数名は出てこないのですが、追加情報がありましたら記載をお願いいたします。

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = [7,8,9]
d = [10,11,12]
names = [a,b,c,d]

for index, name in enumerate(names):
    #for i in enumerate(name):のiは(インデックス, 数値)を返す
    for i in enumerate(name):
        print(i) # (0,1),(1,2),(2,3)...
    #要素だけ取得したい
    for element in name:
        print(element)
    #インデックスだけ取得したい
    for i in range(len(name)):
        print("インデックス {} の値は {} です".format(i, name[i]))
```